# Default handling for "Ctrl + F6" is not working in a customized MDI Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

We have an application which is MDI Based MFC Application inherited using a CFormView class. Issue is that **Ctrl + F6** command is default command for all MDI applications, but in our application it is not working. When I open two or more child windows, and when pressing **Ctrl + F6** the focus doesn't move to the next MDI child windows.

I have tried by creating sample new MFC MDI application and I am able to switch between windows upon **Ctrl + F6** command. I am not familiar with MFC so can any one help me out in this regard.

May I have some ideas what might be the root cause for the above issue.

can i get some exact root cause, why Ctrl+f6 is not working for my customized MFC MDI application because **Ctrl+f6** is supported by Excel sheet and MS word and lot of MDI applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTRL+F6 is the accelerator for next pane and this is only handled inside splitter windows.

This accelerator isn't used in MDI windows at all.

If you want to switch between the MDI windows just add your own OnCommand handler for ID_NEXT_PANE in your CMainFrame (mainfrm.cpp) implementation and use MDINext() and MDIPrev().

PS: The answer was changed after I rechecked the MFC source code. Please excuse.

Comment: i found these in .RC file                                       IDR_MAINFRAME ACCELERATORS                                                  VK_F6, ID_NEXT_PANE, VIRTKEY, NOINVERT
VK_F6, ID_PREV_PANE, VIRTKEY, SHIFT, NOINVERT                   my ProcessMessageFilter function is below                                                           BOOL CAMIBCPApp::ProcessMessageFilter(int code, LPMSG lpMsg) 
{
    if(m_haccel)
    {
        if (::TranslateAccelerator(m_pMainWnd->m_hWnd, m_haccel, lpMsg)) 
            return(TRUE);
    } 
    return CWinApp::ProcessMessageFilter(code, lpMsg);
}

Comment: i am finding difficult in adding comment in a proper way here. pls dont mind.... above comment has RC file Accelerator Table and ProcessMessageFilter() instead of PretranslateMessage() function in my application file.

Comment: i have tried by adding ON_COMMAND Handler OnNextPane() for ID_NEXT_PANE , and called MDINext() in the Handler Function OnNextPane(). but when i press Ctrl+F6 Control is not hitting ON_COMMAND Handler Function OnNextPane().

Comment: The problem here is eventually the command routing. The CView get's the message before the frame receives this. Use your own IDs... define them in the accelerator and use this IDs in the mainframe. Or change the command routing.

Comment: thanks for your fast reply.can you post here piece of code to Add our own ID for Accelerator and Handler. i am just confusing to add code.

Comment: Delete the ID_NEXT_PANE entries from the accelerator. Use the context menu to add a new. Choose your own ID name. Use this in your handler.

Comment: If the comment and answer are helpful, set the question as answered or mark helpful comments.